# How to calculate and evaluate estimators in decomposing interaction models to subgroup models?

Tags: regression, interaction

Suppose we have a simple interaction model (ignoring error terms for simplicity)

Y = b0 + b1X + b2Z + b3X*Z

in which Z is the dummy variable. The model gives values and s.e. of these coefficients.

Now we "decompose" this model into sub-group models:

For Z=0: Y = b0 + b1X

For Z=1: Y = (b0 + b2) + (b1+b3)X

We can calculate coefficient values of sub-group models from the interaction model.

My question is: Can we calculate s.e. of coefficients of sub-group models from the interaction model in some way? Let's say that we have to do it manually, i.e., without a program.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the entire variance-covariance matrix and not just the standard errors (the square root of the diagonal elements), you can do that using the [basic properties of a variance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Basic_properties). So the standard error of $b_0 + b_2$ is:

$\sqrt{\mathrm{var}(b_0) + \mathrm{var}(b_2) + 2\mathrm{cov}(b_0, b_2)}$